# Passing parameters in C with and without " "

Tags: c, parameters, argv, argc

How can i recognize if a parameter is passing with or without " ".
For example:

```
$ ./a.out "Hello I am chain of characters with spaces"  
$ ./a.out Hello I am not a chain of characters with spaces
```

Comment: This is platform-dependent, since the platform (in Linux, the shell) is responsible for parsing the text.

Comment: The quotes here are really part of the shell syntax. They are interpreted by the shell and usually get stripped before the sentence is passed to the program as argument.

Comment: I'm working on Mac. You know, the problem is that during my last exam i had an exercise where i had to do main who won't take parameters without " ".

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are parsed and handled by (in this case) the Linux shell.

In the first case, the shell is essentially doing this:

```
execl("./a.out","a.out","Hello I am chain of characters with spaces", NULL);
```

While in the second case, the shell is doing this:

```
execl("./a.out","a.out","Hello", "I", "am", "chain", "of", "characters", "with", "spaces", NULL);
```

Once your program gets called, the shell has already done the argument handling.  All you can do at that point is to look at `argc` to see how many arguments you have, and to look at each inidividual argument to see if it contains spaces and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Only the best possible answer, but not a *definitive* one. That is, you only know there must have been quotes around an argument **iff** you find at least a single space in it. You cannot discern `a.out hello` from `a.out "hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `argc` (count of arguments). In the first case it'll be 2, in the second it'll be much higher. (2 because element 0 of `argv` will be a.out, element 1 will be the quoted string).